# How do I get this existing mesh to follow this curve?

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, curve-modifier

One thing that I frequently ask myself when using Blender is, "What if I could just make this follow a curve instead of having to model it by hand?"

Unfortunately, I can never seem to get it to work.

Suppose I'm modeling a pair of overalls, and I want one of the loops to follow a curve:

[image: The overalls with a curve modifier.]

Ideally I'd use a curve modifier to achieve this, but it just won't cooperate. I've tried applying all transforms to both the curve and the mesh, but the mesh appears in seemingly random places in the viewport as displayed in the screenshot above.

I've already textured this, so I'd like to keep my existing mesh.

How does one go about doing this?

Comment: it should work, put the two objects at the same location (the origins must overlap) then choose the good Deform Axis it the Curve modifier. That said, I'm not sure that it's the most convenient way to model, if you model with few polygons only it should be easy to give the shape you want to your mesh